# Iterate through array, add the sum as an object into that Array (lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to understand how to iterate through this simple array.

```
var data =  [{"blahh":"hi","blah2":"333","third":"920","fourth":"800"}];
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, appending an object that is the sum of certain keys (the 'third' and 'fourth')...resulting data being this:

```
var data =  [{"blahh":"hi","blah2":"333","third":"920","fourth":"800", "sum": "1720"}];
```

I imagine 'lodash' library is capable of neatly accomplishing this. I just can't figure out how to pull that off. I know this is a newbie question but perhaps answering it may helps some soul better understand lodash.

Comment: You cannot do it with lodash until you understand how to do it _without_ lodash.

Comment: Rubbish. You can learn how to do something with a library and then work out how to do it natively.

Comment: So your question is how to iterate over and array and how to add a property to an object? These questions have been answered before, please use the search.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone, but I think there is a misunderstanding here. I'm aware it can be done without 'lodash', I posed this question because I specifically want to see if it can be done 'neatly' using lodash.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a library to do this ... the code will likely be more complicated looking than using native methods

```
data.forEach(item){
   item.sum = (+item.third || 0) + (+item.fourth  || 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned - you don't need lodash for this. You're looking at the map function to iterate over an array and return a new array (in this case an array of objects returning a new array with objects that have a sum property) and reduce to iterate over all desired keys and sum their values. For example:

```
//If you want to treat numbers as numbers then use numbers.
//Some answers here are coercing strings with + - however this will result in NaN on non coerceable strings -ie 'hello',
//which will cause unexpected errors for you later (and typeof NaN is number)
var data =  [{"blahh":"hi","blah2":333,"third":920,"fourth":800}];

function returnNewArrayWithSums(keys, array) {
  return array.map(obj => {
    obj.sum = keys.reduce((sum, key) => typeof obj[key] === 'number' ? obj[key] + sum : sum, 0);
    return obj;
  });
}

returnNewArrayWithSums(['third', 'fourth'], data);
```

edited to add - this answer is to give you a use case w/ map/reduce - ideally you wouldn't have to specify numeric keys and make this function more general for any arrays that have objects with k/v pairs that are nums that you want to sum

Answer (score -1):

You have an array of one object - which I dont think you are trying to do.  Arrays do not have a key:value pair in them (well actually they do in JavaScript but ignore that).  They are an indexed list of values.  You probably want to do something like this:

```
// notice im not putting the integer values in quotes
var data = {'blah':'hi', 'blah2':333, 'third':920, 'fourth':800 };
data.sum = data.third + data.fourth;
```

That will add a 'sum' field to your object with the value of the sum of third and fourth.  Is this what you are trying to do?